# Как удалить конкретные клавиши в боте Телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

**Собственно сам код:**

```
import telebot

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('api_code_name')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def website(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    done = types.KeyboardButton('0')
    undone = types.KeyboardButton('START')
    markup.add(done, undone)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'WHICH?:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if (message.text == "START"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        a = types.KeyboardButton('0')
        b = types.KeyboardButton('SECOND')
        markup.add(a, b)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'WHICH ONE:', reply_markup=markup)
    elif (message.text == "2"):
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DATE', callback_data='None')
        atom = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PHOTO', callback_data='None')
        markup.add(button, atom)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>!</b>', parse_mode="html", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при выводе сообщения клавиши **'0'** и **'SECOND'** исчезли из интерфейса, а Inline-кнопки  **'DATE'** и **'PHOTO'** - остались?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначала все верно - удалить Reply клавиши.

после удалите сообщение "!", которое отправляется вместе с `ReplyKeyboardRemove` и далее отправьте новое с `InlineKeyboard`:

```
elif message.text == "2":
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('DATE', callback_data='None')
    atom = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PHOTO', callback_data='None')
    markup.add(button, atom)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>!</b>', parse_mode="html", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id + 1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>!</b>', parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)
```